# Windows 8.1 doesn't know it's a tablet

Tags: windows-8, windows-tabletpc

So, recently I've got locked out of my tablet (HP Stream 7) and decided to format it. I just installed a clean version of Windows 8.1 and now I'm noticing that the touchscreen, power button etc don't work.

I've hooked up my mouse & keyboard with OTG and checked drivers etc, but it's kinda hard to update aswell since it doesn't see the Wi-Fi adapter.

I could re-install another 'version' of 8(.1)/10 , but which version must I have for it to know it's a tablet-/pc ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the drivers from the [HP website](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Stream-Tablets/7439994/model/7482041)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to go to the HP support site and download the wlan driver at least, put it on a micro-SD card and install it on your tablet
http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Stream-Tablets/7439994/model/7482041 (please do check if I linked the correct tablet version, could be different)

after installing the appropriate drivers, i recon it should "realize" it's a tablet